# Java what does a protected variable mean in enum type?

Tags: java, java-9

In Java 9, I can write code like this:

```
enum Abc {
    A, B, C;
    static protected int foo = 4; // what is the purpose of the protected variables like this in enum?
}
```

I think it makes no sense, because we cannot inherit or implement an enum.

Edit: This question is the same with [Why are protected members allowed in final java classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661270/why-are-protected-members-allowed-in-final-java-classes)

Comment: Java 8 allows it, too.

Comment: Protected also allows package access if I'm  not mistaken. Doesn't answer your question, but just saying.

Comment: @MadPhysicist It exactly answers the question.

Comment: this question cannot be duplicate of it. please remove this mark. I am asking about enum types.

Comment: @Makoto that’s possible since Java 5, when `enum` types were introduced. Ignoring the fact that this is an `enum`, you can write `/* not public */ class Abc { static protected int foo = 4; }` having an obsolete `protected` modifier, since Java 1.0…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means just what it always means: accessible only from subclasses or classes in the same package. You're right that since you can't inherit the class, it's not any different from a package-private field in practice.

Comment: Using `protected` modifier for a variable can be right option ? Perhaps no one uses this modifier in `enum` for a variable. right ?

Comment: If it does what you want, it's a right option. :-) I agree that stylistically, package-private is probably better.